# How to access the form data from PHP ($_POST not working ??)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I am passing a two dimensional array from a js file to an ajax.php script using $.post method. My .js function looks like this

```
function doSendEmail (aData) {
  var sData = JSON.stringify(aData)
  $.post('dd-ajax.php', { m: 'sendEmail', sData: sData },
    function () {})
    .done(function () { console.log('Done') })
    .fail(function (err) { showMessage(`unexpected error: ${err.responseText}`) })
    .always(function () { spinner(false) })
}
```

Then my Ajax.php file looks like:

```
if ($method == "sendEmail") {
    $sData = array_key_exists('sData', $_POST) ? $_POST['sData'] : NULL;

    foreach($sData as $line) {
        $to = $line[7];
        $name = $line[0];
        $subject = 'Email Subject';
        $message = `Dear $name, Blah blah blah`;
        mail($to, $subject, $message);
    }
}
```

I see my data in the browser in headers > form data, but I don't seem to be able to access anything in Php??

I've tried the above `array_key_exists` and also tried to `$_POST[sData]` but no joy.

I'm kind of a newbie so please be kind

Comment: What does the data you're sending look like? Paste an example.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` and see what your data looks like.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong but it's impossible to say where your code fails because it depends on many variables with unknown value. What's in `aData`? What callback executes? What status code do you get? What does `$_POST` contain? What's `$method`?

Comment: I stand corrected: if `$_POST['sData']` is a string, trying to loop through it can't possibly work. Have you configured PHP to display error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alvaro for pointing me in the right direction. `$method` was being declared earlier in the file as = to the 'm' in the $_GET. Adding an `if` to that has sorted it. Rookie mistake I guess.... Thanks anyway

```
$method = array_key_exists('m', $_GET) ? $_GET['m'] : NULL;
if ($method == NULL) {$method = array_key_exists('m', $_POST) ? $_POST['m'] : NULL;}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
data = { 'm': 'sendEmail', 'sData': sData };
 $.ajax({
        url: 'dd-ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Done');
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
```

in `dd-ajax.php`

```
$method = $_POST['m'];
if ($method == "sendEmail") {
    $sData = array_key_exists('sData', $_POST) ? $_POST['sData'] : NULL;

    foreach($sData as $line) {
        $to = $line[7];
        $name = $line[0];
        $subject = 'Email Subject';
        $message = 'Dear $name, Blah blah blah';
        mail($to, $subject, $message);
    }
}
```